# Add space between Checkboxes and Text of a TreeViewNode

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a TreeView with Checkboxes and want to add spaces between the checkboxes and text of a TreeViewNode. How can I do that?

### Example

```
From:
-A
 -[]b
 -[]c

To

-A
 -[] b
 -[] c
```

Comment: Good luck. Custom painting on the treeview is a bitch of note. This will also screw up hit testing...

Comment: Yes you're right... Next times I should use WPF maybe =)

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was getting no traction.  It is very simple to solve, repost your question and let me know if you are still interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using now http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TriStateTreeViewSubmissio.aspx which solved my problem and give me more flexibility in states.